# Input and loops on a excel imported dataset

Tags: pandas, loops, object, input, dataset

I have a dataset on excel and I want to put it on python. The dataset is basically showing details of clients and all I want to have is a tool that by inputting the client name gives me his number

The data is something like:

client name   client number   client address

Juan           0055522558      street x, 45
.....

Been using pandas to get it all cleaned up and I've actully got the dataset (set is called df) onto python now however I don't understand how to get input message right...

Can anyone help me out please?

Thanks

I'm thinking I should use a

```
choice = input ("enter client name:")
if choice in "client name" == True 
    print("client number is: " ???)
```

How do I make python pick the row of the client name I'm inputting?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to filter the dataframe by `"client name"`. Once the correct row is found, it is easy to obtain the value of the `"client number"` of that same filtered row.

Use a `try - except` statement just in case there are no clients with such name in the dataframe.

Note that if this client has more than one row, just the first client number found in the set will be returned.

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the dataset from the Excel
df = pd.read_excel("clients_data.xlsx")

def get_client_number(input_name):
    try:
        client_number_output = df[df["client name"] == input_name]["client number"].values[0]
        return f"The client number for {input_name} is: {client_number_output}"
    except IndexError:
        return "Client not found."

# Example usage:
client_name_input = input("Enter the client name: ")
print(get_client_number(client_name_input))
```